# Why is the DatePart / DateAdd causing an Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to datatype int Error

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a section of code the is generating an "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to datatype int."  Specifically it's this line....

```
DATEPART(MINUTE, (dateadd(minute, datediff_big(minute,0,(ot.[CheckCloseDateTime])) / 15 * 15, 0))) AS [Minute]
```

When I comment out the two lines related to that column the query completes as it should.  However when un-commented I receive the error.  The [Minute]  Column it is going in to is a Varchar.  The [CheckCloseDateTime] is a DateTime data type.

Any Help is greatly appreciated.

```
INSERT INTO @CloseCheck
(
    [Unitname]
    ,[Location]
    ,[Year]
    ,[Month]
    ,[Day]
    ,[Hour]
    ,[Minute]
    ,[Tables]
    ,[Guests]
    ,[Amount]
)
(
    SELECT
        ot.Unitname
        ,LOWER(REPLACE([Unitname],', ',' '))  AS [Location]
        ,DATEPART(YEAR, (ot.[CheckCloseDateTime])) AS [Year]
        ,DATEPART(MONTH, (ot.[CheckCloseDateTime])) AS [Month]
        ,DATEPART(DAY, (ot.[CheckCloseDateTime])) AS [Day]
        ,DATEPART(HOUR, (ot.[CheckCloseDateTime])) AS [Hour]
        ,DATEPART(MINUTE, (dateadd(minute, datediff_big(minute,0,(ot.[CheckCloseDateTime])) / 15 * 15, 0))) AS [Minute]
        ,COUNT(*) * -1  AS [Tables]
        ,0
        ,SUM(ISNULL(ot.[CheckGrossAmount],0))  AS [Amount]

    --INTO #TempCloseCheck 
    FROM @InitialChecks ot

    GROUP BY  
        ot.Unitname 
        ,DATEPART(YEAR, (ot.[CheckCloseDateTime]))
        ,DATEPART(MONTH, (ot.[CheckCloseDateTime]))
        ,DATEPART(DAY, (ot.[CheckCloseDateTime]))
        ,DATEPART(HOUR, (ot.[CheckCloseDateTime]))
        ,DATEPART(MINUTE, (dateadd(minute, datediff_big(minute,0,(ot.[CheckCloseDateTime])) / 15 * 15, 0)))
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.  There are probably other methods.

Comment: In that line I am trying to round to the nearest 15 minute interval of the [CheckCloseDateTime] fiield.  The column will be used as a dimension.

Comment: From [`DateAdd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments): "_number_
An expression that can resolve to an `int` ...". You get a `bigint`, but it gets converted to an `int` for `dateadd`. If you didn't need to number of minutes from the Beginning of Time (`0`) this would work. Would a base date of `2020-01-01T00:00:00.000` work for you?

Comment: If it minute was 00, 15 30  or 45 yes then I cold just get the minute with a string function

Comment: My bad. [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4b9351f6f97c912b9e901cad35456b82) says that your code is fine until the year 5893. Might there be something else kicking out, e.g. a constraint or trigger? Or are you looking a little farther into the future?

Comment: Not really looking into the future.  I am considering just using a case statement

Comment: Okay, I'll bite. Where does a [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) _expression_ come into it?

Comment: I am trying to get basically get a 15 minute mark.  rather than using the datediff and other date functions I can do it like this `code`    ,CASE 
   WHEN DATEPART(Minute,[CheckCloseDateTime]) Between  00 and 14 THEN '00'
   WHEN DATEPART(Minute,[CheckCloseDateTime]) Between  15 and 29 THEN '15'
   WHEN DATEPART(Minute,[CheckCloseDateTime]) Between  30 and 44 THEN '30'
   WHEN DATEPART(Minute,[CheckCloseDateTime]) Between  45 and 59 THEN '45'
    END `code`

Comment: The `case` returns `( DatePart( minute, CheckCloseDateTime ) / 15 ) * 15` formatted as a two digit string. (Integer division will produce an integer result.) `Right( '0' + Cast( ( DatePart( minute, CheckCloseDateTime ) / 15 ) * 15 as VarChar(2) ), 2 )` is another approach.

Comment: @HABO the above worked.   How can I mark you comment as the answer?

Comment: @user1658938 I've added the comment as an answer with a little more explanation. You can accept and/or upvote the answer. ([What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) explains how.) You can also upvote comments that are useful using the upward pointing triangle next to the comment. That doesn't affect reputation, but it does call attention to useful comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did..

```
        ,CASE 
            WHEN DATEPART(Minute,[CheckCloseDateTime]) Between  00 and 14 THEN '00'
            WHEN DATEPART(Minute,[CheckCloseDateTime]) Between  15 and 29 THEN '15'
            WHEN DATEPART(Minute,[CheckCloseDateTime]) Between  30 and 44 THEN '30'
            WHEN DATEPART(Minute,[CheckCloseDateTime]) Between  45 and 59 THEN '45'
          END  AS [Minute]
```

Answer (score 0):

The case expression returns `( DatePart( minute, CheckCloseDateTime ) / 15 ) * 15` formatted as a two digit string. (Integer division will produce an integer result.)

An alternative approach is to use use that calculation and explicitly add the leading zero, as needed:

```
Right( '0' + Cast( ( DatePart( minute, CheckCloseDateTime ) / 15 ) * 15 as VarChar(2) ), 2 )
```